# How can I use sed to delete blank, unquoted lines?

Tags: string, sed

I'm looking for a `sed` script that will transform

```
;; DONE Badge
;; :PROPERTIES:
;; :ID:       D0C151F1-384E-4995-B091-1EC1FE265572
;; :END:
;; [[http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/badge][Official documentation]]

;; [[file:~/lunch/github/vermiculus/stack-api/stack-api.org::*Badge][Badge:1]]

(defstruct stack-api/badge
  "This type represents a badge on a Stack Exchange `stack-api/site'.

Some badges, like Autobiographer, are held in common across all
Stack Exchange sites. Others, like most tag badges, vary on a
site by site basis.

Remember that ids are never guaranteed to be the same between
sites, even if a badge exists on both sites."

  (award-count nil :type integer)
  (badge-id    nil :type integer) ; refers to a badge
  (badge-type  nil :type (memq 'named
                               'tag-based))
  (description nil :type string) ; unchanged in unsafe filters
  (link        nil :type string) ; unchanged in unsafe filters
  (name        nil :type string)
  (rank        nil :type (memq 'gold
                               'silver
                               'bronze)

  (user        nil :type shallow-user))

;; Badge:1 ends here
```

into

```
;; DONE Badge
;; :PROPERTIES:
;; :ID:       D0C151F1-384E-4995-B091-1EC1FE265572
;; :END:
;; [[http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/badge][Official documentation]]
;; [[file:~/lunch/github/vermiculus/stack-api/stack-api.org::*Badge][Badge:1]]
(defstruct stack-api/badge
  "This type represents a badge on a Stack Exchange `stack-api/site'.

Some badges, like Autobiographer, are held in common across all
Stack Exchange sites. Others, like most tag badges, vary on a
site by site basis.

Remember that ids are never guaranteed to be the same between
sites, even if a badge exists on both sites."
  (award-count nil :type integer)
  (badge-id    nil :type integer) ; refers to a badge
  (badge-type  nil :type (memq 'named
                               'tag-based))
  (description nil :type string) ; unchanged in unsafe filters
  (link        nil :type string) ; unchanged in unsafe filters
  (name        nil :type string)
  (rank        nil :type (memq 'gold
                               'silver
                               'bronze)
  (user        nil :type shallow-user))
;; Badge:1 ends here
```

Bonus points for removing all comments in the same go, but I could use a pipeline for that.  I mainly don't know how to test if the scanner is inside a string or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear whether you can ever get two double quotes on a single line.  Assuming not, then:

```
sed -e '/"/,/"/{p;d;}' -e '/^ *$/d'
```

The first expression matches between pairs of lines containing a double quote, printing each line and deleting it and then reading the next (skipping the second expression).  The second expression deletes blank lines.

If you ever get double quotes on a single line, then you need:

```
sed -e '/".*"/{p;d;}' -e '/"/,/"/{p;d;}' -e '/^ *$/d'
```